# What did Tyler mean, "Like in Boy Scouts"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Fight Club (1999)*, Tyler and Narrator stole  packets of  fat to prepare soaps
at home. Tyler lits on stove and says:

> Tyler: As the fat renders, the tallows float to the surface. **Like in
> Boy Scouts**
>
> Narrator: It's hard to imagine you as a Boy Scout.

What did Tyler mean, "Like in Boy Scouts"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Boy Scouts of America is a youth organization that promotes scouting. The stereotypical activities of scouts includes camping and basic "survival"/crafting skills. Making soap out of leftover fat is here implied to be something you would learn as a boy scout.

Incidentally, the next line references a traditional secondary role of the Boy Scouts to promote good Christian values (I don't think they do this anymore, at least not overtly religiously influenced). Thus "boy scout" is also often used as an insult that someone is too nice or straight-laced.

Comment: Spot on. I think the narrator’s line was implying that Tyler, in his current state, would make an unlikely former Boy Scout. Since, like you mentioned, the Boy Scouts had a reputation for being straight-laced. Tyler is decidedly not straight-laced.